# How do I check for an empty field in a child entry?

Tags: conditionals, related-entries

I have an Event entry which can has one child Location entry. The Location entry has two fields: Title and Floor. Sometimes floor is empty so I'm doing this in my template to see if there's a floor entered:

```
<h2>
  {event_location:title}
  {if event_location:floor}
    , {event_location:floor}
  {/if}
</h2>
```

...and it's not working. Title always shows up and Floor never does unless I take off the conditional, which I don't want to do because I don't want a comma followed by nothing when there's no floor. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to ExpressionEngine Answers huertanix! FYI : It's good form to mark the answer so others can find it, if you get a chance Wes's answer is bang on :)

Comment: It's important to me that I verify that a solution works before I mark it as answered so that I don't mislead anyone with the same problem hoping this is a solution. Since the upgrade failed, I'll try doing surgery on core libraries as suggested and mark it as answered if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the right syntax to use from looking at this question: [Conditionally display a field from a related entry if it's not empty (native relationships field)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/conditionally-display-a-field-from-a-related-entry-if-its-not-empty-native-rel). Basically, the field needs to be compared against an empty string as so:

```
<h2>
  {event_location:title}
  {if '{event_location:floor}' != ""}
    , {event_location:floor}
  {/if}
</h2>
```

Not remotely elegant, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What version are you using? We fixed this problem in 2.9.3, though you can apply [the solution](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20621) if you'd rather not update.

---

Open `system/expressionengine/libraries/channel_entries_parser/Preparser.php` and find the `_find_modified_conditionals()` method around line 374, and **replace** it with this:

```
public function _find_modified_conditionals()
{
    $prefix = $this->_prefix;
    $unfiltered_all_field_names = array();
    $all_field_names = array();

    if (strpos($this->_tagdata, LD.'if') === FALSE)
    {
        return array();
    }

    foreach($this->_channel->cfields as $site_id => $fields)
    {
        $unfiltered_all_field_names = array_unique(array_merge($unfiltered_all_field_names, $fields));
    }

    // Do a rough cut to slim down the number of fields
    // else the string can be too long for the preg_match_all
    foreach (array_keys($unfiltered_all_field_names) as $name)
    {
        if (strpos($this->_tagdata, $name) !== FALSE)
        {
            $all_field_names[] = $name;
        }
    }       

    $modified_field_options = $prefix.implode('|'.$prefix, $all_field_names);
    $modified_conditionals = array();

    if (preg_match_all("/".preg_quote(LD)."((if:(else))*if)\s+(($modified_field_options):(\w+))(.*?)".preg_quote(RD)."/s", $this->_tagdata, $matches))
    {
        foreach($matches[5] as $match_key => $field_name)
        {
            $modified_conditionals[$field_name][] = $matches[6][$match_key];
        }
    }

    return array_map('array_unique', $modified_conditionals);
}
```

Comment: Ah, looks like I'm just one point behind at v. 2.9.2. I'll try upgrading and mark as answered if that works.

Comment: Just spent the day upgrading to 2.10.1. No change.

Comment: Looks like the code function is identical to what 2.10.1 has, so the problem must be elsewhere.